# Laravel graphql lighthouse not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am using **GraphQL Lighthouse** for Laravel 10 project for the first time and I stuck in first phase of API.

I exactly do what documentation said [Link Here](http://dev.laravel-light-graph.test/graphiql) and YouTube tutorial

- Install lighthouse package

  *`composer require nuwave/lighthouse`*
- Publish the default schema

  *`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lighthouse-schema`*
- IDE Support

  *`php artisan lighthouse:ide-helper`*
- Install GraphQL DevTools

  *`composer require mll-lab/laravel-graphiql`*

After that when I hit my project e.g.

> http://localhost/laravel-light-graph/graphiql

It gives me this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected token '<', \"<!DOCTYPE \"... is not valid JSON",
      "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', \"<!DOCTYPE \"... is not valid JSON"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

**Note:** I install this package on fresh Laravel

I didn't write a single line of code for create apis or schema and can't go further from documentation.

I don't know what to do, I searched a lot but didn't get any help. So please guide me on this.

Comment: Can you pls use your browser inspection tool and check the request to see what exception is thrown?

Comment: http://dev.laravel-light-graph.test/graphql/ 403 (Forbidden) ... and when I check the source, it shows empty

Comment: "You can use any GraphQL client with Lighthouse, make sure to point it to the URL defined in the config. By default, the endpoint lives at /graphql"  https://lighthouse-php.com/master/getting-started/installation.html#install-graphql-devtools

Comment: already try it bro ... if I try with `graphql` it gives me 403 error page

Comment: do you have any authentication?

Comment: sorry didn't get you point

Comment: Are you using sanctum? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication

Comment: Nope, I am using simple bootstrap auth